# what are your views on Yoruga and Marimba Ani's critique of European philosophy?

Tags: history-of-philosophy

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marimba_Ani

there is a link where you can see more comprehensive work of her ideas,

she essentially claims that European philosophy is dominated by concepts of control and separation by establishing dichotomies like "man" and "nature"- "thought" and "emotion" etc.

Comment: Could you add more about the substance of her ideas?

Comment: essentially european philosophy tends to separate and create distinctions instead of aiming for unification

Comment: Could you edit that and more into the question?